# Как спарсить ajax через curl

Tags: php, ajax, curl

Всем привет! стоит задача спарсить страницу: https://halykbank.kz/presscenter/novosti. Через нетворк нашел адрес, который как я понял принимает запрос на подгрузку новых новостей. 
Но при переходе по этому адресу вижу только:

```
{"result":false,"hint":"NO_AUTHORIZATION_DATA"}.
```

Подскажите, как можно спарсить эту страницу. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Провайднить авторизацию не хотите?..

Comment: AGS17, подскажите как это обеспечить? Просто там на сайте даже нет возможности зарегаться

Comment: Отправляйте заголовки, идентичные оригинальному запросу. Среди них найдете и Auth-Token

Comment: https://content.screencast.com/users/AGS17/folders/Jing/media/8cd2343e-df8a-4aed-be5a-f7bb238f79f7/2017-06-05_0857.png

Comment: Авторизуйтесь при помощи curl, затем загружайте нужные страницы